# Browser-based local file-system to SVG base64 data string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload, svg

The use case is storing resized svg in database. This question has 2 parts.

1. How to get a data string from loaded image file.
2. How to resize the data string image via canvas.

I've been able to use the following code with window.URL.createObjectURL() to get a nice string but in Angular, I might have the states (ui-router) mixed wrong. So when I click on the link created by console.log

```
function createObjectURL() {
              console.log('file',file);
              return (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(file);

          };

          function revokeObjectURL(url) {
              console.log('url',url);
              return (window.URL) ? window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url) : window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(url);


          };

          (function myUploadOnChangeFunction() {

                      console.log('file',file);
                      var src = createObjectURL(file);
              console.log('src',src);

              var image = new Image();
              console.log('image',image);

              src = src.toLowerCase().replace(/'+/g, '').replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');

                      image.src = src;
                      console.log('image.src',image.src);
              api.testMe = image.src;
              return api.testMe;
              // Do whatever you want with your image, it's just like any other image
                      // but it displays directly from the user machine, not the server!


          })();
```

blob:http%3A//%3A9000/66705b7a-148a-4921-a48b-090fd2ceba52 is the link it gives.

Comment: [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) or [Adobe Indesign](http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/09/exporting-svg-illustrator.html) could help. Havent seen a good browser based converter but I'd try https://cloudconvert.org/png-to-svg

Comment: Cheers Alvin, my main use case is resizing and storing uploads on a client-side AngularJS CMS app. Your link shows that it is possible, obviously any image we can view on the screen can be saved at that quality displayed right? So, we can use html5 canvas tools to manipulate the image and finally output vector svg base64 string to be uploaded to a cloud database document.

Comment: Might be advantageous to see how Emmet encodes / decodes. http://docs.emmet.io/actions/base64/

Comment: Conversion from raster to vector is not a simple procedure, I'm not sure that javascript can do it (it least non-massive code). All that you might get now is a .svg with incapsulated raster image in it. It is no different compared to the regular base64 encoded image. Here, I made some example - http://jsfiddle.net/oe9h352L/

Comment: That's almost a working answer Cheery. Thanks, wonder if it's possible without using fabric.js (200kb minimized is too hefty)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First to get data uri:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log('reader',reader);
        reader.onload = (function(lefile){
               return function(e){
                  console.log("Filereader done");
                  console.log('-- RESULT',e.target.result, '-- NAME:', lefile.name);
```

then to resize (taken from https://github.com/nicam/js-resize/blob/master/resize.js):

```
var resize = function (image) {
    mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    mainCanvas.width = 1024;
    mainCanvas.height = 768;
    var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);
    size = parseInt($('#size').get(0).value, 10);
    while (mainCanvas.width > size) {
        mainCanvas = halfSize(mainCanvas);
    }
    $('#outputImage').attr('src', mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
```

Comment: -1 Does not "How to convert the image via canvas to svg" as you have stated in your question

Comment: @tnt-rox Good point, it was my ignorance to think that canvas was what was necessary to convert an image. FileReader converts the image to base64 data string while canvas is used to resize. Thanks for the attention. I'll fix the question.